# Exit Strategy(Intraday)

Tags: pine-script

new to tradingview. I wanted to create exit strategy including trading session end. So that script exits as per exit strategy(other criteria)  or few mins before
trading session ends which ever is earliest

Answer (score 0):

While you can test for elapsed time in the realtime bar using `timenow - time` if your strategy is using `calc_on_every_tick=true`, you won't be able to reproduce that behavior on historical bars, so will need to run your strat at a small enough timeframe so you can ensure your orders can be executed in time on any bar's close or at the open of the next.